# Count how many times the apps on my phone has been opened

Tags: android

I want to count how often my installed apps open daily,ex:Facebook has opened 10 times

Comment: in your application class create a method that increments the number of app launches and saves that number to the shared preferences and clear it every 24 hours

Comment: i want to count all my applications ex:facebook,google,insta....

Comment: Create a launcher app then you can keep track of that.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read [ask]. You're question is most answerable, if written as text, embeds images (not only show links) and shows what you already tried.

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the App Usage Permission and use the App Usage API:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0#AppUsageStatistics

> You can now access app usage history on an Android device with the new android.app.usage API. This API provides more detailed usage information than the deprecated getRecentTasks() method. To use this API, you must first declare the "android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS" permission in your manifest. The user must also enable access for this app through Settings > Security > Apps with usage access.
>
> The system collects the usage data on a per-app basis, aggregating the data over daily, weekly, monthly, and yearly intervals. The maximum duration that the system keeps this data is as follows:
>
> Daily data: 7 days
> Weekly data: 4 weeks
> Monthly data: 6 months
> Yearly data: 2 years